# Para que serve aquela linha vertical e horizontal quando clica no Form?

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu queria saber para que serve aquela linha vertical e horizontal quando você clica no formulário e fica lá, aí dps quando dá mais outro click, aparece mais outra linha. E tbm como eu posso tirar essas linhas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas linhas são as definições de linhas e colunas de um `Grid`, e server para organizar o layout da aplicação (Ver Imagem). Você pode adiciona-las clicando na parte mais externa do componente (Irá aparecer uma linha laranja onde a linha será adicionada), e pode remove-la dando dois cliques sobre o ponto inicial da linha (aquela seta pra baixo).

Também é possível remove-las pelo código `XAML`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="79*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="240*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="142*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="375*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

[image: Botão Organizado]